# Dynamic String Resource

Tags: java, android, string, textview, android-resources

[Hello], I have a problem.

**Strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="num_e1_n1">%1$d</string>
</resources>
```

In the layout file :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_joueur_e1_n1"
    style="@style/num_joueur"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/maillot_rouge1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/num_e1_n1" />
```

And in the method `onCreate()` in the `.java` file :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saisie_stats);

            // ...

    Resources res = getResources();
    String numero = String.format(res.getString(R.string.num_e1_n1), 98);
    num_rouge1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_joueur_e1_n1);
    num_rouge1.setText(numero);

    num_rouge2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_joueur_e1_n2);
    num_rouge3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_joueur_e1_n3);
    num_rouge4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_joueur_e1_n4);

    //***

}
```

Unfortunately when I run my application, my Textview displays "%1$d"
Except I want it displays 98.
What's wrong? What do I need to change?

Thank you very much.

Comment: just write 98 instead of %1$d  in your resources file and use it like:

String numero = res.getString(R.string.num_e1_n1);

Comment: Sorry, I have not said. I want to use %1$x.
98 it's just an example.
It will Be a variable found in the database.

Comment: @Jéjé  Your line `num_rouge1.setText` _IS NOT_ executed. This is your main problem. Can you confirm it with the debugger or by putting log statements in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
The problem seems to be that you somehow don't succeed to set text programmatically and your `TextView` shows value declared in layout :

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/num_e1_n1" />
```

You can try putting another string in layout to confirm that. Then you have to figure out why your `num_rouge1.setText()` code is not run.

You could try `String.format`, like this :

```
String numero = String.format(res.getString(R.string.num_e1_n1), 98);
```

But it should behave identically to your existing code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes thank you, that's it. But i have no idea why, setText doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that line of code `num_rouge1.setText` is never executed. You have to confirm it with the debugger and find out why. Or post your whole `onCreate` method.

Comment: Done in the first message.

Comment: `onCreate` seems ok, if only it for the right activity : ). Could you please put `Log.d` statement before line `num_rouge1.setText(numero);` and verify you see it (or not as I suspect).

Comment: How? Sorry, but I have never use it, and I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: Just put the line : `Log.d("TEST", "before setting text");` and check whether you see it in the logcat output.